# Why does $_SESSION contain the untrimmed $_POST?

Tags: php, session, post, multidimensional-array, trim

Why doesn't this work?

```
session_start();

print("<pre>".print_r($_POST['foo'],true)."</pre>");  // 'Bob     '

array_walk_recursive($_POST, function (&$val) { $val = trim($val); });
print("<pre>".print_r($_POST['foo'],true)."</pre>");  // 'Bob'

$_SESSION['foo'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
print("<pre>".print_r($_SESSION['foo'],true)."</pre>");  // 'Bob     '
```

Comment: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` does not trim whitespace characters: `Strip tags, optionally strip or encode special characters.` And why switch from `$_POST` to `INPUT_POST`? That kind of inconsistency is asking for issues.

Comment: I suspect that `filter_input()` does not get its data from `$_POST`, but rather from the same place that `$_POST` was originally populated.  That is, altering the contents of `$_POST` does not have any effect on the behavior of `filter_input()`.

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, but I already trimmed the $_POST before I passed it through `filter_input()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [first comment in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php):

> Note that this function doesn't (or at least doesn't seem to) actually filter based on the current values of $_GET etc. Instead, it seems to filter based off the original values.

**edit**

Here's where you would add your call to `trim()`:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

Comment: So I shouldn't trim `$_POST`, but `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Just wrap it around your call to `filter_input()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have quite a few variables. Is there a problem with doing `array_walk_recursive($_SESSION, function (&$val) { $val = trim($val); });` after all the sanitizing?